# Java выполнение действий раз в минуту и бесконечно долго

Tags: java

Подскажите как выполнять определенные действия после запуска приложения и бесконечно долго раз в минуту?

Comment: `java.util.Timer` для самостоятельного приложения. `java.swing.Timer` для swing (есть даже "официальное" руководство. `Timer Services` для приложений javaee. Не знаю как сейчас, но ранее была очень популярна библиотека quartz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Thread run = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        //ДЕЛАЕМ
                        Thread.sleep(1000); //1000 - 1 сек
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        run.start(); // заводим
```

Вот код, п.с Timer это практически тоже самое что и я написал(только оперативку кушае поменьше, объектов на 1 меньше) и вы можете с этим кодом делать что угодно, добавить final boolean(заменить им true) и остановить thread когда вам нужно, а при остановке что-то потворить.

Comment: Вот честно говоря Ваш код помог мне намного лучше реализовать мою задачу. И проще было внедрить и настроить)

Comment: Да и лучше всетаки обработать исключение, я забыл об этом. тоесть InterruptedException вылезет тогда когда кто-то из вне решил ваш поток прервать, тоесть надобы сделать } catch (InterruptedException ex) { break;
                    } а дальше все верно.

Comment: Уже сделал, спасибо))

Answer (score 11):

**java.util.Timer:**

Для использования таймера задача должна быть унаследована от `TimerTask`

```
MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
  public void run() {
    //Этот метод будет выполняться с нужным нам периодом
  }
}

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 60 * 1000); // Время указывается в миллисекундах
```

**java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService**

Для этого примера задача должна реализовывать интерфейс `Runnable`.

```
MyTimerTask implenents Runnable {
  public void run() {
    //Этот метод будет выполняться с нужным нам периодом
  }
}

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Вообще сигнатура метода следующая:

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, initialDelay, period, unit);
```

`command` - Экземпляр класса, реализующего интерфейс java.lang.Runnable

`initialDelay` - задержка перед первым запуском

`period` - периодичность

`unit` - Единица измерения времени. `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` (например: `TimeUnit.MINUTES`)

Comment: Пример с `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` помог. Спасибо Вам большое)

Answer (score 1):

Используй многопоточность. Создай метод котором при вызове создает поток и в его теле будет вот такой while.

```
while(true){
   //doSomething
   Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

Пример: http://www.fandroid.info/klass-thread-i-interfejs-runnable-zhiznennyj-tsikl-potoka-java/

UPDATE: Если вам надо как то его остновить можно просто создать флаг(boolean flag), на место true для остоновки цилка. Да и запустить его можно когда тебе угодлно, лишь бы дать волю фантазии

Comment: такой код крайне сложно менеджить.

Comment: @Etki Это почему же? Да и зачем его менеджить-то?

Comment: @Sergey как вы будете останавливать такую задачу? Как вы будуете ее запускать ровно в хх:00:00?

Comment: @Etki Но по условию задачи запуск осуществляется не по расписанию в xx:yy:zz, а при запуске программы и останавливать не требуется.

Comment: @Sergey я и не написал, что оно не будет работать, я про то, что при любом изменении требований разработка начнет постреливать колено. Да и "раз в минуту" наверное подразумевает раз в 60 секунд, а не раз в (60 секунд + время выполнения).

Comment: @Etki Зачем выдумывать какое-то там "изменений требований", намёка на которое даже близко нет? С таким же успехом можно поменять требование таймера на требование вычислить интеграл методом рунге-кутты.

Comment: @Sergey потому что такой код сложно менеджить.