# Почему после Timer'a не завершает выполнение программы?

Tags: java, таймер

Эксперементирую с Таймером, никак не могу понять почему `main` после трехкратного вывода в консоль стороки `System.out.println("красный" + switcher);` не завршается??? Вот 2 класса:

```
public class NACHALO {
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        Timer tr1 = new Timer();    
        forTimerTask task = new forTimerTask(tr1);

        tr1.schedule(task , 0, 1000);
    }
}
```

и

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class forTimerTask extends TimerTask{

    Timer tTT = new Timer();

    forTimerTask (Timer t){
        tTT = t;
    }
    int switcher = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        switcher++;
        System.out.println("красный" + switcher);

        if (switcher == 3){
            tTT.cancel();
            return;
        }   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (switcher == 3){
    tTT.cancel();
    tTT.purge();
    return;
}
```

`cancel()` завершит все заланированые задачи, а `purge()` очистит очередь, удалив из нее все завершенные задачи

**UPD:**
А еще в классе `forTimerTask`
Строку:

```
Timer tTT = new Timer();
```

Следует заменить на

```
Timer tTT = null;
```

Т.к. тут вы создаете новый таймер, который и не дает завершиться программе.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Как выяснилось в данном случае решающим оказалось заменить строку `Timer tTT = new Timer();` на `Timer tTT = null;` или просто `Timer tTT;` Но чисто логически я не могу это осознать =( 
Ведь дальше по моему коду  `tTT`  присваивается `tr1`, а затем `tTT`, а следовательно `tr1` в его лице, отменяется.

Comment: Он не отменяется, объект висит в памяти, но на него нет ссылок в Вашем коде. А сам таймер, в свою очередь, при создании (`new Timer()`) запускает поток, в который будут направлены задачи, поэтому, он не собирается сборщиком мусора.

Comment: P.S. А вообще, вместо таймера я бы советовал использовать `ScheduledExecutorService` http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536919/java-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be/536935#536935 более продвинутая штука. И не навязывает, чтобы Ваши задачи наследовались от `TimerTask`