# авторизация на сайте по таймеру

Tags: java, android

Интересует следующий вопрос, я авторизуюсь на сайте и если в течении некоторого времени ты не пользуешься сайтом, то происходит автоматический выход из твоего профиля, правильно ли делать таймер на авторизацию и какие еще существуют способы в данном случае? то есть, чтобы каждые 5 минут, к примеру, происходила переавторизация, спасибо.

Comment: В чём суть затеи-то? Держать онлайн статус?

Comment: да, суть именно в этом, как во многих личных кабинетах, дабы пользователю не нужно было заново логиниться каждые 5 мин, все происходило бы автоматически

Comment: Если предположить, что сайт не Ваш, API у него нет, и сессию настроить нельзя - то таки да, нужно слать запросы с периодичностью меньше таймаута разрыва сессии. Либо спросить у юзера пароль и логиниться "втихаря" с желаемой периодичностью.

Comment: А зачем выход из профиля? И что значит "не пользуешься сайтом"? Для авторизации на сайтах обычно используется механизм сессий. Это когда в базе данных сессий на серваке хранится информация о пользователе, который в данный момент авторизировался на сайте, а у пользователя в браузере хранится кука, которая при любом запросе к сайту подтверждает, что этот тот самый авторизированный пользователь. Как только пользователь нажимает кнопку "выйти из профиля", сессия в бд удаляется. Для онлайн статуса надо что-то другое.

Comment: @Сергей, Автовыход при неиспользовании называется - сервер даёт куку с коротким временем жизни и при каждом запросе продлевает. Если кука успела "состариться" - привет незнакомец!

Comment: А зачем так делают? У меня на сайте на джумле так было. Сижу, меняю контент, перезагружаю страницу - оп и я неавторизованный. Неудобно же. Может из соображение безопасности для администраторов?

Comment: @Сергей - к примеру, налайкал "одноклассницам" , а выйти забыл. Жена включила комп - скандал, развод))). Конечно в целях безопасности.

Comment: скорее всего из соображений безопасности)) мало ли

Answer (score 1):

Можно на JAVA таймер запускать. Это пример (не мой, но я работаю так-же). [Java выполнение действий раз в минуту и бесконечно долго](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536919/java-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be/537035#537035)